# Can you help me fix broken latex class file?

Tags: sectioning, document-classes, documentclass-writing

So I am nearing the end of my PhD and need to start writing my dissertation. My university (University of Connecticut) has certain guidelines for the format of the document but does not have an offical LaTex class file. So a (now former) graduate student wrote an unofficial one. Unfortunately, they seem to have broken the star versions of everything below \chapter. I am new to LaTex, but I noticed they used

```
\newcommand\section{...}
```

instead of

```
\def{\section}
...
\secdef\@section\@ssection
```

so I think the problem is in this section of code.

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
    %{\if@center\centering\else\raggedright\fi
    {\raggedright
    \reset@font\s@font}
    }
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    %{\if@center\centering\else\raggedright\fi
    {\raggedright
    \reset@font\ss@font}
    }
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    %{\if@center\centering\else\raggedright\fi
    {\raggedright
    \reset@font\sss@font}
    }
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\reset@font\pg@font}
    }
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\reset@font\spg@font}
    }
```

TLDR:

```
\section*{title}
```

doesn't work as it should and displays

**1.1 ***
title

instead of
**title**
as it should.

How can I fix this given the code above?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: I haven't seen the entire class file, but if it doesn't change the `\@sect` and `\@ssect` macros, I _think_ that those `\raggedright`s are useless...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ooh, history repeats itself. Not more than two months ago someone at my University did the *exact* same mistake.

After the sixth argument there is a spurious space which is tokenized by
TeX while scanning the command. This brings an error when you try to use
`\section*`. As that space is already tokenized, what
you actually use is `\section *`, which fails the `\@ifstar` test and the
section gets numbered. Then another test comes up: `\@ifnextchar[`, which
also fails because the next token is `*`, so the command proceeds to grab
the next token as the section title, that is, you have an `*` for the title.
Finally, what was supposed to be the title of the section is simply
typeset as text.

The definitions should contain end-of-line protection:

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
    %{\if@center\centering\else\raggedright\fi
    {\raggedright
    \reset@font\s@font}% <-- Here
    }
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    %{\if@center\centering\else\raggedright\fi
    {\raggedright
    \reset@font\ss@font}% <-- Here
    }
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    %{\if@center\centering\else\raggedright\fi
    {\raggedright
    \reset@font\sss@font}% <-- Here
    }
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\reset@font\pg@font}% <-- Here
    }
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\reset@font\spg@font}% <-- Here
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! This solved the problem. Thank you!